# Subsonic 3.0 Settings ttinclude for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, subsonic, settings

Is there any subsonic settings.ttinclude template file for oracle db.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Oracle support in SubSonic 3 yet, but recently there has been a person on the SubSonic discussion group working on adding Oracle support.  No ETA on completion.  Here's a link to the group: http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject/topics?start=

Answer (score 0):

According to the SubSonic website, there is [support for Oracle in development](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Supported_Databases#Currently_supported).

The website says to get [the latest T4 Templates for Oracle from GitHub here](http://github.com/stimms/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/tree/master/TemplateProviders/). (which appear to be from the Dec. 2009 - Jan. 2010 time frame.)

I personally haven't tested it myself, but I plan to right now. I'll try to post back with my results.